# Need distinct results for command-delimited string aggregation

Tags: sql, db2, concatenation, substr

I Have the following query that works just need to know how to only show DISTINCT results in the M_Item field also would be nice if the query sorted these results as well.

```
SELECT 
    CUSTOMER AS TN,
    substr
    (
       xmlserialize( xmlagg( xmltext( concat( ', ', ITEM) ) ) as varchar( 1024 ) ), 3 
    ) as M_Item
FROM ORDERS
WHERE ITEM LIKE 'CP%'
GROUP BY CUSTOMERS;
```

Currently Results show:

```
Customer    M_ITEM
JON         CP024, CP025, CP027, CP028, CP029
MIKE        CP905, CP906, CP028, CP029, CP027
JULIE       CP024, CP025, CP027, CP028, CP029
SAM         CP114, CP024, CP025, CP027, CP028, CP029
SEAN        CP024, CP025, CP027, CP028, CP029, CP024, CP025, CP027, CP028, CP029
```

I want them to show like this:

```
Customer    M_ITEM
JON         CP024, CP025, CP027, CP028, CP029
MIKE        CP027, CP028, CP029, CP905, CP906 
JULIE       CP024, CP025, CP027, CP028, CP029
SAM         CP024, CP025, CP027, CP028, CP029, CP114
SEAN        CP024, CP025, CP027, CP028, CP029
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the distinct items from the table before using the `xmlserialize` function:

```
SELECT 
    CUSTOMER AS TN,
    substr
    (
        xmlserialize( xmlagg( xmltext( concat( ', ', ITEM) ) ) as varchar( 1024 ) ), 3 
    ) as M_Item
FROM 
    (
        select distinct customer, item
          from ORDERS
         WHERE ITEM LIKE 'CP%'
    ) as x;
```